# hive cross join with where clause stops during reduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, cross-join

I ran a cross join on 2 tables (size: table_a ~ 100k rows, table_b ~ 200 million rows) like the following in hive:

```
select a.id, a.first_name, a.last_name, a.street
     , b.pid, b.first_nam, b.last_nam, b.strt
from table_a a
  cross join table_b b
where
  (a.phone_number in (b.phone_1, b.phone_2)
   and a.birth_date in (b.birth_date_1, b.birth_date_2))
  or
  (
  cast(a.zip_code as int) = cast(b.zip_code as int)
  and
    (
      (
      upper(a.last_name) = upper(b.last_nam)
      and a.birth_date in (b.birth_date_1, b.birth_date_2)
      )
      or
      (
      a.phone_number in (b.phone_1, b.phone_2)
      )
      or
      (
      a.birth_date in (b.birth_date_1, b.birth_date_2))
      and upper(a.street) = upper(b.strt))
      )
    )
  );
```

The job started on the cluster and showed that 160 mappers and 1 reducer were chosen to run it. And the map part finished quite quickly (in about 3 minutes). The reduce started and it ran slowly but steadily going from 1%, 2%, 4%, ... until it hit 67%. Then it just stagnated for over 30 minutes with no progress. Although it showed that the accumulated CPU time increased some (from about 3500 seconds to 4200 seconds). But the reducer just won't go beyond 67%. Eventually I had to cancelled the job and tried to rerun it. I got the same behavior each time. I tried to increase the # of reducers by setting options like:

```
set mapred.job.reduces=10;
```

But it still showed only using 1 reducer whenever I run the query. Any idea what is going on here and how I may solve the problem?

**Edit**: here is the output

```
INFO  : Stage-1 is selected by condition resolver.
INFO  : Number of reduce tasks determined at compile time: 1
INFO  : In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
INFO  :   set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
INFO  : In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
INFO  :   set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
INFO  : In order to set a constant number of reducers:
INFO  :   set mapreduce.job.reduces=<number>
INFO  : number of splits:160
INFO  : Submitting tokens for job: job_1484094252811_0005
INFO  : Kind: HDFS_DELEGATION_TOKEN, Service: ha-hdfs:nameservice1, Ident: (HDFS_DELEGATION_TOKEN token 53 for hive)
INFO  : The url to track the job: redacted
INFO  : Starting Job = job_1484094252811_0005, redacted
INFO  : Kill Command = /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.0-1.cdh5.5.0.p0.8/lib/hadoop/bin/hadoop job  -kill job_1484094252811_0005
INFO  : Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 160; number of reducers: 1
INFO  : 2017-01-11 14:11:36,957 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
INFO  : 2017-01-11 14:11:49,499 Stage-1 map = 1%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 10.45 sec
INFO  : 2017-01-11 14:11:50,549 Stage-1 map = 2%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 17.03 sec
INFO  : 2017-01-11 14:11:51,610 Stage-1 map = 21%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 1100.63 sec
INFO  : 2017-01-11 14:11:52,674 Stage-1 map = 22%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 1181.04 sec
INFO  : 2017-01-11 14:11:54,773 Stage-1 map = 40%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 1744.29 sec
INFO  : 2017-01-11 14:11:55,819 Stage-1 map = 41%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 1769.61 sec
INFO  : 2017-01-11 14:11:57,903 Stage-1 map = 58%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 2444.53 sec
INFO  : 2017-01-11 14:11:59,988 Stage-1 map = 62%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 2505.06 sec
INFO  : 2017-01-11 14:12:01,032 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 2999.97 sec
INFO  : 2017-01-11 14:12:12,486 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 2%, Cumulative CPU 3051.65 sec
INFO  : 2017-01-11 14:12:21,878 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 3%, Cumulative CPU 3084.96 sec
INFO  : 2017-01-11 14:12:27,088 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 4%, Cumulative CPU 3108.88 sec
INFO  : 2017-01-11 14:12:36,477 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 5%, Cumulative CPU 3132.38 sec
INFO  : 2017-01-11 14:12:45,837 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 6%, Cumulative CPU 3153.54 sec
INFO  : 2017-01-11 14:12:55,204 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 7%, Cumulative CPU 3181.5 sec
INFO  : 2017-01-11 14:13:01,437 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 8%, Cumulative CPU 3204.99 sec
INFO  : 2017-01-11 14:13:10,781 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 9%, Cumulative CPU 3231.7 sec
INFO  : 2017-01-11 14:13:17,012 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 10%, Cumulative CPU 3255.17 sec
INFO  : 2017-01-11 14:13:25,320 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 11%, Cumulative CPU 3280.29 sec
INFO  : 2017-01-11 14:13:31,560 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 13%, Cumulative CPU 3300.07 sec
INFO  : 2017-01-11 14:13:40,903 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 14%, Cumulative CPU 3326.19 sec
INFO  : 2017-01-11 14:13:47,133 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 15%, Cumulative CPU 3345.77 sec
INFO  : 2017-01-11 14:13:56,473 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 16%, Cumulative CPU 3370.6 sec
INFO  : 2017-01-11 14:14:02,696 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 17%, Cumulative CPU 3392.17 sec
INFO  : 2017-01-11 14:14:11,142 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 18%, Cumulative CPU 3416.55 sec
INFO  : 2017-01-11 14:14:17,365 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 19%, Cumulative CPU 3436.33 sec
INFO  : 2017-01-11 14:14:26,710 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 20%, Cumulative CPU 3458.24 sec
INFO  : 2017-01-11 14:14:32,926 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 21%, Cumulative CPU 3477.13 sec
INFO  : 2017-01-11 14:14:42,262 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 22%, Cumulative CPU 3504.41 sec
INFO  : 2017-01-11 14:14:48,485 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 23%, Cumulative CPU 3532.08 sec
INFO  : 2017-01-11 14:14:56,778 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 24%, Cumulative CPU 3561.15 sec
INFO  : 2017-01-11 14:15:02,997 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 25%, Cumulative CPU 3581.73 sec
INFO  : 2017-01-11 14:15:12,319 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 26%, Cumulative CPU 3607.59 sec
INFO  : 2017-01-11 14:15:18,543 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 27%, Cumulative CPU 3631.92 sec
INFO  : 2017-01-11 14:15:27,878 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 28%, Cumulative CPU 3655.75 sec
INFO  : 2017-01-11 14:15:34,094 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 29%, Cumulative CPU 3677.59 sec
INFO  : 2017-01-11 14:15:40,369 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 30%, Cumulative CPU 3703.33 sec
INFO  : 2017-01-11 14:15:49,687 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 31%, Cumulative CPU 3726.21 sec
INFO  : 2017-01-11 14:15:52,789 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 32%, Cumulative CPU 3730.8 sec
INFO  : 2017-01-11 14:15:57,964 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 33%, Cumulative CPU 3748.92 sec
INFO  : 2017-01-11 14:16:07,269 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 59%, Cumulative CPU 3765.56 sec
INFO  : 2017-01-11 14:16:10,377 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 67%, Cumulative CPU 3769.25 sec
INFO  : 2017-01-11 14:17:10,449 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 67%, Cumulative CPU 3804.54 sec
INFO  : 2017-01-11 14:18:10,459 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 67%, Cumulative CPU 3804.54 sec
INFO  : 2017-01-11 14:19:10,521 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 67%, Cumulative CPU 3804.54 sec
INFO  : 2017-01-11 14:20:10,569 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 67%, Cumulative CPU 3804.54 sec
INFO  : 2017-01-11 14:21:11,569 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 67%, Cumulative CPU 3804.54 sec
INFO  : 2017-01-11 14:22:12,566 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 67%, Cumulative CPU 3804.54 sec
INFO  : 2017-01-11 14:23:12,587 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 67%, Cumulative CPU 3804.54 sec
```

Comment: *...how I may solve the problem?* - Don't do a cross join.

Comment: @GoBrewers14 not a solution though. What can you recommend instead?

Comment: I can help but you'll have to describe what the data looks like and what you want the output to be.

Comment: @GoBrewers14 I thought the question was pretty clear. My goal is to match the records from two tables by using name, address, etc. In reality I do have more columns but those are not used in matching so they are irrelevant to the question of how.

Comment: I did more research and found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171806/reducers-stopped-working-at-66-68-while-running-hive-join-query). It seems that my query stopped at 67%, which is the start of the actual reduce after shuffle and sort. Either my query has an infinite loop or the size of the data is too large for the cluster.